# bash appending to file inside and outside the loop

Tags: bash

What is the difference between those two commands?

```
while true; do date; sleep 1; done > /tmp/log
```

vs

```
while true; do date >> /tmp/log; sleep 1; done
```

Both append to file one line a time but seems that both do it different way.

I thought that first one won't append anything to file because the whole appending to file will happen after the loop ends, and because the loop is infinite nothing will ever be written to file.
Also how is possible that first one is appending to file when only one `>` is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 1, output is added to the file immediately because the `date` command flushes its output when it exits, which writes everything to the standard output file.

Version 1 isn't appending to the file. It opens a file descriptor to the file when the loop starts, and empties the file when that happens.  This descriptor stays open for the entire loop, and is inherited by each command in the loop as its standard output. Since it's not closed and reopened before each command, the file is not truncated each time -- they just write to the current position in the file.

Comment: Thank you, I did my little research based on your question with: `strace -ff -o strace_out_v1 sh -c 'while true; do date; sleep 1; done > /tmp/log'`, `strace -ff -o strace_out_v2 sh -c 'while true; do date >> /tmp/log; sleep 1; done'`, `grep log strace_out_v1*` and `grep log strace_out_v2*`

Answer (score 2):

For the first command

```
while true; do date; sleep 1; done
```

is seen as a "block". Anything that block outputs is printed to `stdout`. You are simply redirecting the output of that block to a file.

Imagine you had the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do date; sleep 1; done
```

And now you ran

```
script.sh > /tmp/log
```

You would also expect the log file to be continuously written to.

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```
while true; do date; sleep 1; done > /tmp/log
```

opens the file immediately (before the loop ever even runs) (and truncates any existing content in the file) and the commands that run inside the loop inherit the open file descriptor (fd) and any output is written to that fd as the output happens.

This command:

```
while true; do date >> /tmp/log; sleep 1; done
```

opens the file once each time through the loop (immediately before running the `date` command). The `>>` operator opens the file in append mode so the existing file contents are not truncated away.